# Count occurence of an array using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
var status = ['Inprocess', 'Hired', 'Rejected', 'Inprocess'];
var count = [];
for (var i = 0; i < status.length ; i++) {
  if(count[status[i]]){
    count[status[i]]++;
  } else {
    count[status[i]] = 1;
  }
}
```

I have an array status and I am trying to count the occurrence of the status values and getting the result in count array.

I am getting the result as:

```
count = ["Inprocess" : 2, "Hired" : 1, "Rejected" : 1]
```

Whereas I want the result to be:

```
count = [2,1,1]
```

Please help.

Comment: Why is the first data structure not good enough? The second is seemingly meaningless unless you know what the order of the words is. Also, is your example correct? (rejected = 3?)

Comment: I agree, the second data structure makes no sense, as it is dependent on the order of the original array.

Comment: *"using jquery"* - You're not currently using jQuery, nor do you need it. Your current output is required at least as an intermediate working step (though you should be using an object rather than an array), but as has been pointed out already your desired output is a little hard to actually use on its own. Anyway, you can map your existing values to get a plain array: `count = Object.keys(count).map(v => count[v])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one `window.status` is a property of `window`, and for two you seem to be confusing your `Array` notation with your `Object` notation.  I also don't know why you're getting 'Rejected: 3' when there's only one such item in the array.

I suggest wrapping your code in a function so that the 'status' variable has local scope (or better still, pass it as an argument to the function), then use a hashtable to count the occurrences of each array element, and finally run through that Object to return the result of the counting as an array.  Something like...

```
function statusCount(status) {
    var count = {};

    status.forEach(function(s) {
        count[s] = count[s] ? ++count[s] : 1;
    });
    //count = {Inprocess: 2, Hired: 1, Rejected: 1}

    return Object.keys(count).map(function(c) {
        return count[c];
    });
}

var sCount = statusCount(['Inprocess', 'Hired', 'Rejected', 'Inprocess']);
console.log(sCount);
//=> Array [ 2, 1, 1 ]
```

Passing the 'status' array as an argument to the function will allow you to reuse the function as and when.

The output seems pretty random and in itself gives little clue to what the values actually relate to - but hopefully the example will give you some ideas about an approach to counting instances of elements in an array.

Comment: Why not `Object.keys(count).map(c => count[c])`?

Comment: Might want to note to the OP that you're using ES6 notation and that's not going to work unless he's using a preprocessor?

Comment: @RickCalder ES6 working in latest Firefox, but you you're right - I'll fill it out a bit.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's getting native adoption, but we're no where near using it without Babel just yet lol.